# Save Matplotlib plot image into Django model

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, plot

For learning purposes I'm making a webapp that make plots with matplotlib, and I want to save the image of that plot into the `figure` field of the Plot model but when I make a plot all it does it saves a blank image into the `/media/figures/` directory. I did this the way an other post suggested but it's not working.

**More Info**
When I make the plot, the plot image gets saved in the main directory of my django project with a name like `<_io.StringIO object at 0xb1ac69ec>`, but as I said the plot image that gets saved in the model is blank. Also im using **Python 2.7** if that matters.

```
def simple_plot(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        xvalues = request.POST.get("xvalues")
        yvalues = request.POST.get("yvalues")
        plots.simple_plot(request, name, xvalues, yvalues)
        messages.success(request, "Plot created!")
        redirect("plots:create")
    return render(request, 'plots/simple.html')
```

The file which plots are made and plot instances created.

```
def simple_plot(request ,name, xvalues, yvalues):
    file_name = name+".png"
    xvalues = [int(x.replace(" ","")) for x in xvalues.split(",")]
    yvalues = [int(y.replace(" ","")) for y in yvalues.split(",")]

    figure = io.StringIO()
    plot = plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
    plt.savefig(u'%s' % figure, format="png")

    content_file = ContentFile(figure.getvalue())
    plot_instance = Plot(name=name, user=request.user)
    plot_instance.figure.save(file_name, content_file)
    plot_instance.save()
    return True
```

Plot Model

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    figure = models.ImageField(upload_to='figures/')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Could you post what the Plot model looks like? What does ContentFile do?

Comment: I added the Plot model, ContentFile/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You should not save the figure to a `StringIO` but instead, a `io.BytesIO()`. This is because the contents of the PNG file isn't human-readable text but binary data.
- Another problem is how you handle the `BytesIO` (`StringIO` in your code) when passing it to `savefig`. A `BytesIO` isn't associated with a file (that's the whole point of having an in-memory file-like object), so it doesn't have a file name – which is what I suppose you want to get at by that `u'%s' % figure` expression. Instead, just write to the file-like object itself.
- Third, use a `django.core.files.images.ImageFile` instead of `ContentFile`. Also, initialise it with the `BytesIO` object itself, not its bytes value.

The relevant portion of your code then becomes:

```
figure = io.BytesIO()
plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
plt.savefig(figure, format="png")
content_file = ImageFile(figure)
```

Comment: I tried this but the same thing is happening, I added some more info in the post maybe it'll help.

Comment: I'm going to try it out in a Django project as I cannot see any other mistake immediately from the code. That part about a file with a funny name being saved to your project directory should be gone, however, once you update your code to directly save to plot to `figure`. The funny name is exactly the result of that mistaken `u'%s' % figure` expression.

Comment: Oh wait, I do spot something else: Maybe you should not directly use `ContentFile` but a subclass of it that also mixes in `django.core.files.images.ImageFile`. If that doesn't help, you can also place a debugger after the call to `savefig` to check whether figure.getvalue() looks like the content of the image file you expect. That yould at least tell you whether the error is in the plotting or on the Django side.

Comment: I tried using the `ImageFile` but the same thing is happening, also when I use `plt.savefig(figure, format="png")` I get `unicode argument expected, got 'str'` so I'm using `plt.savefig(unicode(figure), format="png")`

Comment: See the updated answer. If it still doesn't help, ask again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you might also want to try the plotly library - they have a js script that you can add to the html (https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/) and you can always serialize the arrays needing to be imported into the graph

Answer (score 0):

Working version:

```
import io
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

figure = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(figure, format='png')
content_file = ContentFile(figure.getvalue())
one_round.chart.save('chart.png', content_file)
```